# PyQt4 code not working on PyQt5 (QHeaderView)

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5

I was using PyQt4 and this code works great.

```
self.table.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

It's stretching a column in a table.
But when I run the code with PyQt5, I'm getting this error:

```
Attribute Error: 'QHeaderView' object has no attribute 'setResizeMode'
```

Can you please help? Or simply; how can I strect any column in PyQt5?

Answer (score 15):

Use [QHeaderView.setSectionResizeMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode) instead of [QHeaderView.setResizeMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qheaderview-compat.html#setResizeMode):

> Use setSectionResizeMode instead.

(Quote from documentation for [QHeaderView.setResizeMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qheaderview-compat.html#setResizeMode))

Answer (score 11):

In PyQt5 should be:

```
header = self.table.horizontalHeader()       
header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```